# Call form validation function by clicking link

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to be able to click a link on my form and have it call the form's validation function (but not actually submit it!).

Here's what I've got that's partially working:

in form_alter:

```
$form['my_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#field_suffix'] = "<a id='link_validate' href='#');'>Validate</a>";
```

in js file:

```
Drupal.behaviors.my_form = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
        $('#link_validate', context).click(function () {
            $("#edit-preview").click();
        });
    }
};
```

If you access the form from the node edit page, then this way works. However, if you access the form normally, it won't work the first time the page loads. If you hit Refresh, then it will work, but not on first load. I know the Javascript is getting called, as I've put an alert() statement in the above click function and it shows up, but it's like Drupal is blocking the .click() on first load for some reason. I've also tried .mousedown() and .trigger() without luck.

Any ideas?